# Delete model resource link in Action Mailer View

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having a bit of trouble generating a link in Action Mailer that allows the resource to be deleted when clicked. Here's my code for the delete method (which works fine inside of the app):

```
def destroy
    @registrant = Registrant.find(params[:id])
    @registrant.destroy
    flash[:danger] = "Your registration has successfully been cancelled."
    redirect_to root_url
    RegistrantMailer.cancellation_email(@registrant, @registrant.event).deliver_now
    rescue
      flash[:warning] = "No registration record found."
      redirect_to root_url
  end
```

Here are the routes for the application:

```
Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                     Controller#Action
         registrants POST   /registrants(.:format)          registrants#create
          registrant GET    /registrants/:id(.:format)      registrants#show
                     DELETE /registrants/:id(.:format)      registrants#destroy
static_pages_contact GET    /static_pages/contact(.:format) static_pages#contact
  static_pages_about GET    /static_pages/about(.:format)   static_pages#about
              events GET    /events(.:format)               events#index
                     POST   /events(.:format)               events#create
           new_event GET    /events/new(.:format)           events#new
          edit_event GET    /events/:id/edit(.:format)      events#edit
               event GET    /events/:id(.:format)           events#show
                     PATCH  /events/:id(.:format)           events#update
                     PUT    /events/:id(.:format)           events#update
                     DELETE /events/:id(.:format)           events#destroy
                root GET    /                               static_pages#home
```

And here is the link from the mailer in which I want to generate the delete link:

```
<p>Can't make the event? Click here to cancel your registration: <%= link_to 'Destroy', @registrant, method: :delete %> </p>
```

Comment: inspect the html link inside a generated email. Try following the link and make sure your controller action is being hit. If you get that far, you've narrowed the problem down to your controller action. By the way, the code you've shown doesn't have any access control, i.e. anyone could still delete anyone.

Comment: I inspected it before posting and while it was hitting the right controller and action, the error was raised because the browser always sends a GET request and the delete action uses a DELETE. Thanks for pointing out the access control, I actually have a few methods in the controller and I'm adding a token to authenticate the email link.

Comment: if it was hitting the correct controller action how could it be resolved by changing the HTTP method? All the HTTP method does is route to a controller action. Anyway glad you figured it out

Comment: Well essentially Active Record raises and error saying that no delete path for GET exists. But as I mentioned below I resolved it by simply sending a link to the edit path which loads in the browser and has a button to delete the resource.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ability to issue PUT and DELETE statements from within Rails views is due to the extra work Rails does to format the links and issue requests that are universally understood by the browser.  Typically, browsers will only know how to use HTTP verbs GET and POST when performing form submissions and requesting documents.  Rails allows the other verbs to be used by issuing a POST request, and by supplying an HTTP header stating that the request should be interpreted as a DELETE request by the server, for example.

When you use the `link_to` helper in a mailer view, the additional javascript that Rails uses to convert and issue the request isn't present, and thus the link when clicked will send a GET request with no additional information.

There are really 2 options:

1: Make the registration able to be canceled via a GET request.  (This is the easiest method, but not preferred, as it would allow anyone to issue a GET request to this endpoint and delete a registration.  This has happened before with web crawlers issuing GET requests in order to index pages, and inadvertently deleting many records).

2: Have the link in the mailer view direct to a GET accessible landing page in Rails.  Once the user is here, the landing page will have additional instructions, and the DELETE link which will work, because the browser once again has access to the Rails javascript helpers.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up just going with number 2 and putting in a link to the edit action and then creating a delete button there.